# Cross region code deploy error.(AWS Codepipeline)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

I try to cross region deploy from ap-southeast-1 to ap-northeast-1 using AWS CodePipeline.
But, an below error is occurred  deploy phase.
I set s3 full access to CodeStarWorker-test-ToolChain.

---

ReplicationStatus Replication of artifact 'test-BuildArtifact'
failed: Failed replicating artifact from
source_backet in ap-southeast-1
to dest_backet in ap-northeast-1: Check source and destination
artifact buckets exist and
arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/CodeStarWorker-test-ToolChain has
permission to access it.

---

I set below config to deploy of pipeline. 
Does any one have same error and know reservation?

```
               {
                 "name": "Deploy", 
                 "actions": [
                     {
                         "region": "ap-northeast-1",
                         "inputArtifacts": [
                             {
                                 "name": "test-BuildArtifact"
                             }
                         ], 
                         "name": "GenerateChangeSet", 
                         "actionTypeId": {
                             "category": "Deploy", 
                             "owner": "AWS", 
                             "version": "1", 
                             "provider": "CloudFormation"
                         }, 
                         "outputArtifacts": [], 
                         "configuration": {
                             "ActionMode": "CHANGE_SET_REPLACE", 
                             "ChangeSetName": "pipeline-changeset", 
                             "RoleArn": "arn:aws:iam:: xxxxxxx:role/CodeStarWorker-test-CloudFormation", 
                             "Capabilities": "CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM", 
                             "StackName": "awscodestar-test-lambda", 
                             "ParameterOverrides": "{\"ProjectId\":\"test2\",
 \"CodeDeployRole\":\"arn:aws:iam:: xxxxxxx:role/CodeStarWorker-test-CodeDeploy\"}",

                             "TemplateConfiguration": "test-BuildArtifact::template-configuration.json", 
                             "TemplatePath": "test-BuildArtifact::template.yml"
                         }, 
                         "runOrder": 1
                     }, 
                     {
                         "region": "ap-northeast-1",
                         "inputArtifacts": [], 
                         "name": "ExecuteChangeSet", 
                         "actionTypeId": {
                             "category": "Deploy", 
                             "owner": "AWS", 
                             "version": "1", 
                             "provider": "CloudFormation"
                         }, 
                         "outputArtifacts": [], 
                         "configuration": {
                             "StackName": "awscodestar-test-lambda", 
                             "ActionMode": "CHANGE_SET_EXECUTE", 
                             "ChangeSetName": "pipeline-changeset"
                         }, 
                         "runOrder": 2
                     }
                 ]
             }
         ], 
         "artifactStores": {
             "ap-southeast-1": {
                 "type": "S3", 
                 "location": "source_backet"
             },
             "ap-northeast-1": {
                 "type": "S3", 
                 "location": "dest_backet"
             }
         }, 
         "name": "test-Pipeline", 
         "version": 1
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I've seen this error it's been one of two things.

1. You don't have your S3 bucket replicated to the bucket being used in the second region. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr.html
2. Your step is running before the replication is complete.

If it's the latter I'm always able to re-run the step and it succeeds. Seems to be an issue with the S3 replication not moving fast enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will recheck CRR.

Comment: @D.Yamashita did you ever find resolution to this? I am experiencing the same issue, and no where in AWS's documentation does it state CRR is required on your artifact stores.

Comment: @Jason, sorry to late. Thank you comment.

Comment: @Johnrad I could not resolve this problem. But CodeStar was released in ap-northeast-1 reagion. So, replication was not necessary...

Comment: Did you got the solution for this, as per @jason, i have added the s3 replica and i can see that the both the buckets (1 in dev aws us-east-1 and the other prod aws account in mumbai) getting buildartifcats replicated, still am getting the error as Yamashita mentioned. Can any one help ? being stuck this by 2 days

Comment: CodePipeline now does the replication for you, but you have to give the role that the pipeline is using the appropriate permissions. This is a big improvement because it can handle more than two regions and it doesn't have the issue with replication not completing.

Comment: @Jason: thanks for the response. I have given s3 full access still getting the error.

Comment: Are you seeing the artifacts replicated to the artifact bucket in the region you are seeing the error? Did you turn off other forms of replication? I noticed that it would show an error even if the file was there because it failed to put it there (i.e. another process put it there).

Comment: yes artefacts are copied to other buckets. I checked the status of replication showing "COMPLETED" . To create  a delay i created a manual approval step so that it gives enough time to replicate even, still no luck.

Comment: If you still have S3 bucket replication on you need to turn that off. That isn't required anymore. I would open a new question and give as many details as you can. It's difficult to help within the comments of another answer.